# Compiler error with the batch

Tags: apex, rest-api, batch, integration

```
public with sharing class APTS_UsageInput_InsertTempRecordsBatch implements Database.Batchable<APTS_UsageInputWrapper>
{

    public List <APTS_UsageInputWrapper> inputList = new List<APTS_UsageInputWrapper>();
    public List<EQ_TempSSP1Data__c> tempData = new List<EQ_TempSSP1Data__c>();
    list<APTS_UsageInputWrapperData> inputlistData= new list<APTS_UsageInputWrapperData>();

    public APTS_UsageInput_InsertTempRecordsBatch(List<APTS_UsageInputWrapper> uirecordsfromloadfile)
    {
        inputList = uirecordsfromloadfile;

    }


    public Iterable<APTS_UsageInputWrapper> start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return inputList;
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext info,List<APTS_UsageInputWrapperData> inputlistData) 
    {
        // insert tempssp1 records
        integer counter = 1;

        for (APTS_UsageInputWrapperData record : inputlistData) {
            tempData.add(new EQ_TempSSP1Data__c(EQ_WorkId__c =
                    inputList.EQ_WorkId,
                    EQ_SourceSystem__c = record.EQ_SourceSystem,
                    EQ_IssueNumber__c = record.EQ_IssueNumber,
                    EQ_ServiceCode__c = record.EQ_ServiceCode,
                    EQ_Quantity__c = record.EQ_Quantity,
                    EQ_QuantityID__c = record.EQ_QuantityID,
                    EQ_RecordKey__c = record.EQ_RecordKey,
                    EQ_LoadMonth__c = system.today()));

            counter++;
        }
        insert tempData;
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext info) { }
}
```

> Error: Class APTS_UsageInput_InsertTempRecordsBatch must implement the 
>         method: void Database.Batchable.execute(Database.BatchableContext, 
>           List)

I am trying to pass APTS_UsageInputWrapper wrapper from class to batch.

```
       global class APTS_UsageInputWrapper {

global String EQ_WorkId { get; set; }
global Integer EQ_Count { get; set; }
global Boolean ValidateOnly { get; set; }
global List<APTS_UsageInputWrapperData> data { get; set; }
```

}

```
public class APTS_UsageInputWrapperData {
//RefCode
public string EQ_IssueNumber { get; set; }

//FeeCode
public string EQ_ServiceCode { get; set; }

public decimal EQ_Quantity { get; set; }

public string EQ_QuantityID { get; set; }

public string EQ_SourceSystem { get; set; }

public string EQ_LoadMonth { get; set; }

public string EQ_RecordKey { get; set; }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the class signature:

```
public with sharing class APTS_UsageInput_InsertTempRecordsBatch 
implements Database.Batchable<APTS_UsageInputWrapper>
```

Make sure you consistently apply "generics" in your Batchable implementation, as covered in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm):

```
public Iterable<APTS_UsageInputWrapper> start(Database.BatchableContext context)
```

and:

```
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<APTS_UsageInputWrapper> scope)
```

and:

```
public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context)
```

Any other signatures will cause you compilation issues. Any other errors revealed after that are not related to the incorrect generics usage you currently have.

You have used APTS_UsageInputWrapperData instead of APTS_UsageInputWrapper in the signature for execute.

It is the execute method that needs updating; you need to iterate the wrappers and from the wrappers get the wrapper data. You then use a combination of the wrapper-level data and the wrapper data's data to create the EQ_TempSSP1Data__c instances.

Perhaps something like:

```
    List<EQ_TempSSP1Data__c> data = new List<EQ_TempSSP1Data__c>();

    for (APTS_UsageInputWrapper wrapper : scope) {
        for (APTS_UsageInputWrapperData record : wrapper.data) {
            tempData.add(new EQ_TempSSP1Data__c(EQ_WorkId__c =
                wrapper.EQ_WorkId,
                EQ_SourceSystem__c = record.EQ_SourceSystem,
                EQ_IssueNumber__c = record.EQ_IssueNumber,
                EQ_ServiceCode__c = record.EQ_ServiceCode,
                EQ_Quantity__c = record.EQ_Quantity,
                EQ_QuantityID__c = record.EQ_QuantityID,
                EQ_RecordKey__c = record.EQ_RecordKey,
                EQ_LoadMonth__c = System.today()));
        }
    }

    insert data;
```

As an aside, since you are using an Iterable-based batch please note that:

1. this restricts you to a maximum of 50000 underlying database objects for your processing (e.g. if you use a query to populate the "inputList" you can only use up to 50000 objects to do this).
2. you should use generics against the iterable's type as well; note that List<APTS_UsageInputWrapper> can be returned as an Iterable<APTS_UsageInputWrapper> from your start method

Comment: i tried with same but now getting again error:  Class APTS_UsageInput_InsertTempRecordsBatch must implement the method: void Database.Batchable<APTS_UsageInputWrapper>.execute(Database.BatchableContext, List<APTS_UsageInputWrapper>) .. I have updated my wrapper in code.

Comment: It is hard to be exact as to your problem because you have not included what the relationship is between APTS_UsageInputWrapper and APTS_UsageInputWrapperData.

Comment: Fundamentally you need to make sure the code uses APTS_UsageInputWrapper, extracting the APTS_UsageInputWrapperData from the wrapper when the data is needed.

Comment: I have added inner wrapper also. Could you please have a look and let me know what changes can i do.

Comment: Thanks Phil, it worked. :)

Comment: If start returns null then the batch will do nothing; you need to return the list of wrappers you want processed.

Comment: Thanks Phil, for providing such deep clarification. It was very usefull and had great learning.